# How to copy parameters and return type of function?

Tags: typescript

I have function `x` and I have function `y`. How can I make function `y` have all the same parameter and return types as function `x`? Essentially I'd like to make them identical, except for their inner workings (everything in between `{` and `}`).

I know I can use `Parameters<typeof x>` and `ReturnType<typeof x>` but was wondering if there was a single utility that does everything in one hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof x` will give you the full type:

```
const x = (a: string, b: number): boolean => { return true }

const y: typeof x = (a: string, b: number): boolean => { return false }

// leaving the individual types out, but they're still string, number, boolean
const implicitY: typeof x = (a, b) => { return false } 

// This misuse of `typeof x` shows typescript errors
const badY: typeof x = (a: number, b: string): boolean => { return 'hi' }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAFAQwFw2gJwJZgDmANDAEZZgCuAtmQKY4CUWZIIANvWmEgHwwA3jBz0oVHLyg4q9GAF8AUItCRYATyxR1AB3ogAZvCSpM2aQRLlKtBs1bsuPfkJFiJvA2g4Q5SxQD0ATBOAG6WMFAAFnIEACZ44XFU3pG69BAwIFRQpGQ5kTHqAOSi5ngcHOb4RKTUdIx5jtxgKuDQMHg0Ohx4wHhQAJpa6YbGyOh5TC7CouKSMF4%20fjDKQTAAKlF4mTQ7VL5ZRgAG2npjcMeFOCAA7pmMNxBtauRoccNp50YIE2b1djyWFwlhY5GazkQAlm7gWxW2xQUQA)